# My checkbox on the gridview doesn't trigger an event

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, gridview, checkbox

I created my gridview with checkboxes inside of it with this code.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="366px" autogeneratecolumn="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="SelectAllCheckBox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" oncheckedchanged="SelectAllCheckBox_OnCheckedChanged" />
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="EachCheckBox" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

I tried check/uncheck it.
[enter link description here](http://image.ohozaa.com/view2/wed9EBjiOdjLMAq0)

```
protected void SelectAllCheckBox_OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String test = "test";
        test = "newtest";
        GridView1.DataSource = null;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

But it doesn't trigger any event.
[enter link description here](http://image.ohozaa.com/view2/wed9EXhZ5UMnrzQe)

I'm trying to find where my code is missing and searched so far but still can't.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your code is OK, worked for me. Could you post the way you are populating `GridView1`? If it is refilled on every postback - it will prevent `CheckedChanged` event from being handled.

Answer (score 0):

You must use OnItemCreated or OnItemDataBound and link your checkbox with your delegate

```
   void Item_Created(Object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e) 
   {

      CheckBox cbx = (CheckBox)e.Item.FindControl("SelectAllCheckBox");
      cbx.CheckedChanged += SelectAllCheckBox_OnCheckedChanged;

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine and works for me.

I suspect you might be binding the GridView on every postback.

When you click the CheckBox with the event attached it causes the page to refresh. If you bind the CheckBox on Page_Load (or any method that occurs on every trip to the server) it will bind the grid every time you click the CheckBox.  In this case it will never get as far as firing your event.

If so, try checking for a postback before binding your GridView.

For example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Gridview1.DataSource = myDataSource;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```